# Blank & TAB Problem Inside HereDOC in Powershell (Or An alternative way for long text)

Tags: powershell, tabs, heredoc

How can I leave spaces and tabs between heredoc tags?

**My Functions**

```
function random_ascii () {    $text=@"
        _    ____   ____ ___ ___      _         _        _             _     _           
       / \  / ___| / ___|_ _|_ _|    / \   _ __| |_     / \   _ __ ___| |__ (_)_   _____ 
      / _ \ \___ \| |    | | | |    / _ \ | '__| __|   / _ \ | '__/ __| '_ \| \ \ / / _ \
     / ___ \ ___) | |___ | | | |   / ___ \| |  | |_   / ___ \| | | (__| | | | |\ V /  __/
    /_/   \_\____/ \____|___|___| /_/   \_\_|   \__| /_/   \_\_|  \___|_| |_|_| \_/ \___|
    "@    write-output $text }

random_ascii
```

I cannot put tab or blank **last ending tag for heredoc** -- "@ --, why does it crash when i do this

```
$text1 = @" this is wrong, why is this wrong usage? "@

$text2 = @"
    This is also wrong,
    "@

$text3 = @" this is OK
"@
```

**Another Example:**

```
    $Menu1 = @'
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
    Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
    when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
    It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,
    remaining essentially unchanged.
    '@

$Menu2 = "Hello Wold"
```

> The command ($Menu2) does not work because I put whitespace characters
> in the heredoc value $Menu1. I want to put spaces in the code block **(including start and end tags)** as
> it gives an ugly look, but I can't. Is there a way I can do that?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From the [`about_Quoting_Rules` help topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules#here-strings) (emphasis added):

> A here-string:
>
> - spans multiple lines
> - **begins with the opening mark followed by a newline**
> - **ends with a newline followed by the closing mark**
> - includes every line between the opening and closing marks as part of a single string

That is, the newline following the opening mark (`@"<newline>`) and preceding the closing mark (`<newline>"@`) are part of the string literal boundaries.

So if you want to last line of the constructed string value to contain, then it has to go *before* that last newline (`` `t `` is the escape sequence for the TAB character in an expandable string):

```
@"
<ASCII art goes here>
`t
"@
```

With your second example, you can simply keep the inline whitespace - all you need to do is remove the spaces before the `'@`:

```
$Menu1 = @'
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
    Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
    when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
    It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,
    remaining essentially unchanged.
'@ # now the parser won't complain

$Menu2 = "Hello Wold"
```

Comment: Actually, the thing I'm stuck with is that when I adding blanks the tag in the last line in the code block, it gives a compile error.

Comment: @IchigoKurosaki Did you read the explanation from the documenation? You cannot have any other whitespace characters between the newline and the end mark. What is the exact error message?

Comment: Yes I have already read. So, I am trying to find an alternative way to be able to put whitespace characters between these tags or another alternative way. Because it gives a very ugly look to my code block.

Comment: @IchigoKurosaki It's only the whitespace between the last newline and the end mark you need to remove - the leading whitespace on previous lines is still part of the string literal. Just avoid indenting `"@`/`'@` in the source code and you'll be fine. See updated answer

Comment: I know that, but I insistently want to put a space here==> blanks    '@

Comment: @IchigoKurosaki I can't help you with that, you're gonna have to rewrite PowerShell's parsing engine for that to work :)

Comment: yes unfortunately :S or is there any other good way to put a long string

Comment: @IchigoKurosaki You could store your string in a separate text file and read it with `Get-Content`

Comment: yes it can, but I don't want it that way either, it has to be read directly from memory

Comment: @IchigoKurosaki Can you explain _why_ you insist on not just conforming to the language's syntax rules? Is it an aesthetic thing (end mark aligning with first non-whitespace character)? Or is it because you're using an editor that isn't quite PowerShell-aware that tries to format your code? Or something else?

Comment: I added a picture for this :)